# how can i trigger only one tab key if the tab key is pressed numerous times in a certain time period

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i trigger only one tab key if the tab key is pressed numerous times in a certain time period or if the tab key is pressed and held in.Basically i want the tab key to move slowly between input fields regardless of how tab is pressed because currently it is moving to fast.

```
var tab_counter = 0;
var time_counter = 0;

if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    tab_counter = Number(tab_counter) + Number(1);

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        time_counter++;
        console.log(time_counter);
        if (time_counter == 20 && tab_counter > 20) {
           clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 60); 
}
```

Comment: What event are you attaching too.  If your using keydown you will get multiple, but if you use keyup you will just get 1.

Comment: Search for 'Debouncing'

Comment: @Novice I'd have searched for throttling, but to the same effect! - https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it is to keep track of when the tab was last triggered and to `preventDefault` when it should not trigger. If you add the event listener to the `document` then every time the user presses a key you have the option to block it.

Check this jsfiddle i created to show you the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/zLsbb0kh/1/

Cheers!